# Filter on conditionals with two columns

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

I want to remove cities that have `NA` values in the `value` column if `crime` = `"total"`. So I don't just want to remove the row with the `NA` value but I want to remove all the rows of that city.

Here's an example data frame:

```
df <- structure(list(city = c("Amsterdam", "Amsterdam", "Amsterdam", 
"Rotterdam", "Rotterdam", "Rotterdam"), year = c(2015L, 2016L, 
2017L, 2015L, 2016L, 2017L), crime = c("total", "total", "total", 
"total", "total", "total"), value = c(5000L, 5190L, NA, 4901L, 
4830L, 4659L)), .Names = c("city", "year", "crime", "value"), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), spec = structure(list(
    cols = structure(list(city = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), year = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
    "collector")), crime = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), value = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
    "collector"))), .Names = c("city", "year", "crime", "value"
    )), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector"))), .Names = c("cols", "default"), class = "col_spec"))
```

I prefer solutions in in the `dplyr` package.

Comment: `df[!df$city %in% df$city[df$crime == 'total' & is.na(df$value)],]`

Comment: We don't use the language on the title. That is why we have tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easier to read chunk:

```
city_List <- df%>%filter(is.na(value) & crime == "total")%>%distinct(city)
df%>%filter(!city %in% city_List)
```

One-liner:

```
df%>%filter(!city %in% list(filter(df,is.na(value) & crime == "total")%>%distinct(city))[[1]])
```